# I want to create a new WordPress page template for a totally different design

Tags: php, html, wordpress

My WordPress website is http://www.travel-safer.com

I want to integrate one of my new html design as a dynamic page template into current website. The new HTML design is totally different from current design.

My HTML design is  http://www.rohitdesigns.co.nf

Please suggest me what steps i should follow ?

Comment: wordpress has some good docs on [Theme Development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

Comment: if header section and footer is different then you can't render header/footer normally like it does...like. Try creating a pagetemplate  and inside that add all new layout including the new header/footer section

Comment: @RahulS How i should call new header and footer files in a new page template ?

Comment: You have to write the new header and footer content in the page template itself. Since its not having the same layout of other pages